# how to resize image which is loaded from server using javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

this is my code below.

In the code, `imgurl` is the URL for image which loads image from server but I want to resize it and I am unable to do it. `mname` is the list id. I want to show the image and the merchantname in the list but I'm getting very large image size.

```
$('#mname').append(
    '<li>' +
        '<a href="#">' +
            '<img src="'+ imgurl +'" >' +
            '<h4>' + somename.tName + '</h4>' +
        '</a>' +
    '</li>'
);
$("#mname").listview("refresh");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could use jQuery's `.width()`

Example:

```
$('li img').width(300);
```

Changes all images in `li` elements to have 300px width.

Answer (score 2):

Do you just want to change the image size for displaying purpose?

Just set the css class name for `<img>`

```
'<img class="myimageclass" src="'+ imgurl +'" >'
```

then set css for that class

```
.myimageclass {
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give image a **id** like **myimage**

and use this code:

```
$('#myimage').width(700); // Units are assumed to be pixels
$('#myimage').height(700);
```